# Electron External Content/npm

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I know from the [Electron docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security) that external/remote content is not to be trusted and a good way of mitigating the risks associated with using this content is to turn nodeIntegration off, load into a webview, etc.

Do the warnings about external content apply to modules included in the app via npm, i.e., if I use any code I did not write I should enable the above controls? Or are these warnings more about loading a remote file via a script tag or dumping a web page to the app via a call to loadUrl?

Comment: Remote content can be tampered / edited after creating a build. NPM modules cannot, since they are bundled at the build. Just be careful which module you use and you should be fine.